# What would be a correct approach for this conditional probability problem involving card selection without replacement?

Tags: probability, card-games

The question reads:

"Three cards are randomly selected, without replacement, from an ordinary deck of $52$ playing cards. Compute the conditional probability that the first card selected is a spade given that the sec- ond and third cards are spades."

This is my attempt, which I know is incorrect. I would like an explanation for why the reasoning was incorrect

$P(A)=$ First card is a spade

$P(B)=$ Second card is a spade

$P(C)=$ Third card is a spade

So, we want to find $P\left(A \vert B\cap C\right)$ $$P\left(A \vert B\cap C\right)= \frac{P\left(A \cap B\cap C\right)}{P\left(B\cap C\right)}$$

For the numerator we choose $3$ out $13$ cards out of a possible ${52 \choose 3}$.

For the denominator we choose $2$ out of a remaining $12$ cards out of a possible ${51 \choose 2}$

Our final answer should be $\frac{\frac{{13 \choose 3}}{{52 \choose 3}}}{\frac{{12 \choose 2}}{{51 \choose 2}}}= 0.25$

The given answer is $0.22$. Their solution includes using a lot of properties of probability conversions. If that is the only correct way to solve this problem, there is no reason to explain it since I have the explanation.

I was wondering what's wrong with my approach, and if it's not a simple numerical error, why this approach is incorrect.

Comment: Are you able to answer if the question read instead "*What is the probability that the third card is a spade given that the first two cards are spades?*"  Are you able to reason that the answer to this different question should be the same as the answer to the first?

Comment: As for your attempted answer, you do have an error.  Your denominator you used $\dfrac{\binom{12}{2}}{\binom{51}{2}}$.  Why?  It *should* have been $\dfrac{\binom{13}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}$.

Comment: I see where my problem is now. I was using $P\left(B \cap C\vert A\right)$ instead of $P\left(B \cap C\right)$, correct?

Comment: That is correct.  Once you simplify your fraction, you'll arrive at an answer of $\frac{11}{50}$, which is as alluded to the same answer to the question I pose in my first comment.  In general, you can draw your cards in whatever order you want: third card first then first card then second card or what have you.  There is a proper formal argument you can make as to why this is involving bijections between ways of drawing in the standard order versus drawing in an unusual order.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the probability that a spade is drawn from a pack of 50 cards with 11 spades? $11/50$.

Or by the method you attempted:

$$\mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C) ~{= \dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)}{\mathsf P(B\cap C)} \\= \dfrac{\binom{13}3/\binom{52}3}{\binom{13}2/\binom{52}{2}} \\ = \dfrac{11}{50}}$$

Reason: $\{B\cap C\}$ is the event of drawing two spades when drawing two cards from the full deck .   That the position of these cards is second and third is irrelevant.